# Como recuperar todas as URL de um site qualquer?

Tags: php, url, google-analytics-api

Estou a fazer um densevolvimento especifico, e gostaria de coletar todas as **URL** de um site qualquer.

No meu site por exemplo consigo fazer isso usando o **google analytics**, pra outras sites nao consigo pois nao tenho acesso.

Existem ferramentas que poderiam ajudar-me nesse caso ?

Comment: Tente assim: [Web Spider – Captura Links de Website](https://desenvolvimentoaberto.org/2014/02/23/web-spider-captura-links-de-website/).

Comment: Com PHP pode fazer um curl da página e depois com alguma classe de analisar o DOM da página vc vasculha as tags <a> e checando o src vai guardando os links.
https://www.tutorialspoint.com/php/php_dom_parser_example.htm

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Depois de algumas pesquisas encontrei uma alternativa. 
Installei **[Xenu](http://home.snafu.de/tilman/xenulink.html#Download)** uma solução gratis que permite recuper todas as **URL** do site e muito mais.

Um outro metodo seria o uso do **PHP** usando a **curl** da pagina !

Answer (score 1):

Não é bem o que queres, mas este site, por exemplo, devolve te o sitemap inteiro de um endereço web qualquer.

[Gerar Sitemap](https://www.xml-sitemaps.com)

O site vai gerar o sitemap num xml, podes aproveitar depois os links desse ficheiro.